# Custom property does not show in properties window

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I would like a custom control to provide a different `BackColor` based on the value of `Enabled` property. I inherited a `Button`, and now trying to shadow `BackColor` property to hide it from the view, and then provide another one, called `BackColorEnabled`.

Here is a reduced test case for the issue:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Friend Class StyledButton : Inherits Button
  Private _BackColorEnabled As Color

  <Browsable(False)>
  Friend Shadows Property BackColor As Color
    Get
      Return MyBase.BackColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
      MyBase.BackColor = value
    End Set
  End Property

  <Browsable(True)>
  Friend Property BackColorEnabled As Color
    Get
      Return _BackColorEnabled
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
      _BackColorEnabled = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Sub New()
    _BackColorEnabled = SystemColors.Control
  End Sub

End Class
```

The problem is that both properties have no effect, i.e. `BackColor` is still showing up, and `BackColorEnabled` is not there. According to many links I've found on the net, setting `BrowsableAttribute` should work 100%. So what's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that *WinForms designer* does not like when properties are declared as `Friend`, and completely ignores them as such, even if using a control from the same assembly. After I changed both to `Public`, it worked like a charm.

As far as I can see, it should not pose a scope problem, because the class itself can remain `Friend`.

**Side note:** I first spend considerable time debugging this issue in a bigger project. Then started gathering thoughts about asking a question on SO. Prepared a reduced test case - and then found a solution in a few minutes. Just thought it would be nice to share my findings with the community.

Comment: I knew about Public regarding trying to hide BackColor - the scope has to match as if it goes by a signature, but you were quick.  Something related I just ran into: w/ctl inherit from ListView, I want to shadow/consume `Headerstyle`, but it would not fall of the properties list...it was case sensitive. As soon as I changed it to `HeaderStyle` (capital S) it went away.  I've toggled it back and forth 2-3 times to make sure it wasnt something else.  Same thing with `BackColor` vs `Backcolor`.  If you leave off Shadows, VS will complain, but wont REALLY shadow it unless case matches! maybe a bug